# If cell contains "name" then change adjacent cell to "number"

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

In my excel workbook column **C** contains a list of names and column **E** contains a list of phone numbers. The names are pasted in each night from another workbook and the phones are manually entered to match the names. The names are always changing position each day, they can be in any cell on column **C**

How can i automatically fill in the correct numbers (which correspond to the names)? I can make a sheet containing Names & Numbers as a mini database for excel to take data from but i don't know how to tie this into my main sheet.

***In other words:*** If a cell in column **C** contains a specific name then change the adjacent cell in column **E** to the correct phone number

Comment: [`VLOOKUP()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)? What have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I was googling IF statements but they seem to only work on small changes. Im dealing with around 50 names and 50 numbers across 2 columns & the names & numbers change position every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `=VLOOKUP(c2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$10,2,false)` in col E where `Sheet2!$A$1:$B$8` is your names & phone numbers.